# ListControl/LineChart graphs are not displaying due to a server error in Experience Analytics

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-analytics

Installed `Sitecore 9 Update 1` together with `Sitecore Experience Commerce 9 Update 1` on my dev VM.

When I go to Experience Analytics, I can see these exceptions instead of charts:

[image]

It is showing this excception not only for Goals but basically any board.

**Here are textual representations of exceptions:**

> The ListControl list cannot be displayed due to a server error. Contact you system administrator.
>
> The LineChart graph cannot be displayed due to a server error. Contact you system administrator.

**And here is exception that I can see in Developer toolbar in Firefox:**

> {message: "An error has occurred.", exceptionMessage: "An error occurred while sending the request.",…}
>   exceptionMessage
>   :
>   "An error occurred while sending the request."
>   exceptionType
>   :
>   "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException"
>   innerException
>   :
>   {message: "An error has occurred.",…}
>   exceptionMessage
>   :
>   "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."
>   exceptionType
>   :
>   "System.Net.WebException"
>   innerException
>   :
>   {message: "An error has occurred.",…}
>   exceptionMessage
>   :
>   "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."
>   exceptionType
>   :
>   "System.IO.IOException"
>   innerException
>   :
>   {message: "An error has occurred.",…}
>   exceptionMessage
>   :
>   "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"
>   exceptionType
>   :
>   "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException"
>   message
>   :
>   "An error has occurred."
>   stackTrace
>   :
>   "   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   ↵   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)"
>   message
>   :
>   "An error has occurred."
>   stackTrace
>   :
>   "   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   ↵   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)"
>   message
>   :
>   "An error has occurred."
>   stackTrace
>   :
>   "   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
>   ↵   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)"
>   message
>   :
>   "An error has occurred."
>   stackTrace
>   :
>   "   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
>   ↵   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Repositories.ReferenceData.ReferenceDataSegmentReader.Get(IEnumerable`1 keys, NameValueCollection readingPreferences)
>   ↵   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.Repositories.AggregationSegmentReader.Get(IEnumerable`1 keys, NameValueCollection readingPreferences)
>   ↵   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.RequestTypeResolver.GetReportSegments()
>   ↵   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.RequestTypeResolver.GetRequestType()
>   ↵   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.Http.ModelBinding.ReportQueryModelBinder.GetModelFromBindingContext(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
>   ↵   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.Http.ModelBinding.ReportQueryModelBinder.BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
>   ↵   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinderParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   ↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.d__0.MoveNext()
>   ↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   ↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   ↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   ↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()
>   ↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   ↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   ↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   ↵   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
>   ↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   ↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   ↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   ↵   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
>   ↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   ↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   ↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   ↵   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
>   ↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   ↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   ↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   ↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()
>   ↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   ↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   ↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()
>   ↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   ↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   ↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   ↵   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"

**This is what I can see in Sitecore log:**

> 5340 09:58:15 INFO  Cache created: 'ExperienceAnalytics.DimensionItems' (max size: 2MB, running total: 7120MB)
>   5340 09:58:15 ERROR [Sitecore Services]: HTTP GET
>   URL http://sxc9.sc/sitecore/api/ao/aggregates/all/46511EC0EC7A492BA90F96BAB33B7456/all?&dateGrouping=collapsed&&dateFrom=04-04-2018&dateTo=02-07-2018&keyGrouping=by-key
>
> Exception System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Repositories.ReferenceData.ReferenceDataSegmentReader.Get(IEnumerable`1 keys, NameValueCollection readingPreferences)
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.Repositories.AggregationSegmentReader.Get(IEnumerable`1 keys, NameValueCollection readingPreferences)
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.RequestTypeResolver.GetReportSegments()
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.RequestTypeResolver.GetRequestType()
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.Http.ModelBinding.ReportQueryModelBinder.GetModelFromBindingContext(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.Http.ModelBinding.ReportQueryModelBinder.BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
>      at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinderParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()
>   5340 09:58:15 ERROR [Sitecore Services]: HTTP GET
>   URL http://sxc9.sc/sitecore/api/ao/aggregates/all/46511EC0EC7A492BA90F96BAB33B7456/all?&dateGrouping=collapsed&&dateFrom=04-04-2018&dateTo=02-07-2018&keyGrouping=by-key
>
> Exception System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Repositories.ReferenceData.ReferenceDataSegmentReader.Get(IEnumerable`1 keys, NameValueCollection readingPreferences)
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.Repositories.AggregationSegmentReader.Get(IEnumerable`1 keys, NameValueCollection readingPreferences)
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.RequestTypeResolver.GetReportSegments()
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.RequestTypeResolver.GetRequestType()
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.Http.ModelBinding.ReportQueryModelBinder.GetModelFromBindingContext(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.Http.ModelBinding.ReportQueryModelBinder.BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
>      at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinderParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()
>   2376 09:58:15 ERROR [Sitecore Services]: HTTP GET
>   URL http://sxc9.sc/sitecore/api/ao/aggregates/all/46511EC0EC7A492BA90F96BAB33B7456/all?&dateGrouping=by-auto&&keyTop=8&keyOrderBy=visits-Desc&dateFrom=04-04-2018&dateTo=02-07-2018&keyGrouping=by-key
>
> Exception System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginReceive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Repositories.ReferenceData.ReferenceDataSegmentReader.Get(IEnumerable`1 keys, NameValueCollection readingPreferences)
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.Repositories.AggregationSegmentReader.Get(IEnumerable`1 keys, NameValueCollection readingPreferences)
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.RequestTypeResolver.GetReportSegments()
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.RequestTypeResolver.GetRequestType()
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.Http.ModelBinding.ReportQueryModelBinder.GetModelFromBindingContext(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.Http.ModelBinding.ReportQueryModelBinder.BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
>      at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinderParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()
>   2376 09:58:15 ERROR [Sitecore Services]: HTTP GET
>   URL http://sxc9.sc/sitecore/api/ao/aggregates/all/46511EC0EC7A492BA90F96BAB33B7456/all?&dateGrouping=by-auto&&keyTop=8&keyOrderBy=visits-Desc&dateFrom=04-04-2018&dateTo=02-07-2018&keyGrouping=by-key
>
> Exception System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginReceive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Repositories.ReferenceData.ReferenceDataSegmentReader.Get(IEnumerable`1 keys, NameValueCollection readingPreferences)
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.Repositories.AggregationSegmentReader.Get(IEnumerable`1 keys, NameValueCollection readingPreferences)
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.RequestTypeResolver.GetReportSegments()
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.RequestTypeResolver.GetRequestType()
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.Http.ModelBinding.ReportQueryModelBinder.GetModelFromBindingContext(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.Http.ModelBinding.ReportQueryModelBinder.BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
>      at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinderParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.<ExecuteBindingAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
>   4228 09:58:15 ERROR Exception when executing agent aggregation/pathAnalyzerHistoryAgent
>   Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
>   Message: An error occurred while sending the request.
>   Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
>      at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
>      at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory)
>      at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.Initialize(XmlNode configNode)
>      at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
>      at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
>      at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
>      at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient(String clientConfigPath)
>      at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.Agents.TreeAggregatorAgent.Execute()
>      at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
>   Message: An error occurred while sending the request.
>   Source: mscorlib
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__37.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.d__32.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.ConfigurationWebApiClient.d__4.MoveNext()
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.Net.WebException
>   Message: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
>   Source: System
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.IO.IOException
>   Message: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>   Source: System
>      at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
>   Message: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>   Source: System
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

Anyone encountered this issue before? What should I check? WHat should be resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the root cause and also solution thanks to **Vlad Iobagiu** who pointed me to right direction on Slack.

Unfortunately, it is not so obvious from exceptions and StackTrace.

Problem was that the SSL certificate was not specified / selected for `xconnect` site in IIS Manager:

[image]

When I set it to correct certificate, everything started to work as expected like before:

[image]

[image]

However don't know how this could be possible. How certificate was reset to nothing.